# couldn't connect mongodb to kafka

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, mongodb-kafka-connector

i'm trying to connect monodb to kafka so whenever a new document is inserted into mongo i will have the data sent to a kafka topic.
so i've installed mongodb connector using confluent hub, configured MongoSourceConnector.properties like this :

```
name=mongo-source
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
tasks.max=1

# Connection and source configuration
connection.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/
database=dev
collection=users

topic.prefix=newuser
poll.max.batch.size=1000
poll.await.time.ms=5000

# Change stream options
pipeline=[]
batch.size=0
change.stream.full.document=updateLookup
collation=
```

restarted confluent kafka and inserted some new docs into mongo but i see nothing on kafka, no new topics are created and nothing seems to work ! am i missing something here ? is there something else that i should configure/run ?

thanks :)

Comment: Can you check your Kafka Connect worker log for any errors and update your question if there are. Also what is the status of the connector when you set it running?

Comment: Sounds like something (quite possibly Kafka Connect) is already running on that port

Comment: yes i stopped connect and i run connect-standalone and it seems like it's working now, is there a way to do so using kafka connect ?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.